# php regex: modify to only allow one word

Tags: php, html, regex, wordpress

I'm using the contact form 7 plugin for wordpress in combination with contact form db to display the field results in the front end. I'm trying to filter out the results in the shortcode, e.g.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[cfdb-value form="Testing" filter="FirstField~~/^s/"]'); ?>
```

This filter will only show values of `FirstField` that start with the letter `s`, is it possible to adapt this code to only show one word values (i.e. words with no spaces in). If this is at all possible? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try `^\w+` instead of `^\s`. \w means "Word character without whitespace", "+" means "one or more". I'm not sure if you also have to escape the backslash (`\\ instead of \ `) since I don't know how the function handles it.

Comment: @MichaelHelwig this is only showing results that start with `w`. I want to only show results that consist of 1 word (i.e. no whitespace)

Comment: Then the function doesn't seem to interpret the regex correctly. Have you tried escaping (two backslashs instead of one)?

Comment: @MichaelHelwig yes, still doesn't work :( that's the problem I'm having. I'm using the filtering technique documented here: http://cfdbplugin.com/?page_id=89#filter as I'm trying to filter out the results in the front end but it doesn't seem to be interpreting them correctly and I can't figure out what to do :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a regex that won't non-words (including punctuation). It allows unicode though:

```
/^\w+$/u
```

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/bU9zF0)

**Pass**:

- `correct`
- `foobar`
- `definitelynot`
- `unicodeæøå`

**No pass**:

- `foo bar`
- `bar-foo`
- `foo.bar`
- `noway, sir`

Answer (score 0):

Try `^s[a-zA-Z0-9]\*$`   Start with s and followed by any number of characters inside brackets `[]`. Other way would be `^s[a-zA-Z0-9]\*\S$` which insists whitespace to be in the end of word! I did not test this code, but idea should be there.

Comment: I'm just looking to filter out the results with whitespace, the `start with s` validation isn't needed anymore. I have used this code before though, which didn't work as putting parentheses inside the shortcode breaks the shortcode :(

Comment: Stack overflow removed \* from my first answer... it must be there!

Comment: What was your first answer? Stack Overflow won't remove your answer until they have a reason

Comment: If you need any word just remove s  try   ^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$

Comment: @Low Surely you mean `+` and not `*`. You wouldn't allow an empty string.

Comment: this should be even better /[^\s\\\]/

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:

```
/^(\S+)/
```

This capture all characters that are not spaces from the beginning of the string.

Comment: still no luck :( usually this regex would work, but as the regular expressions are inside the shortcode, some and reading as they should. The 's at the start of the word' one works fine, thus I used that as an example, but trying to only show 1 word (no whitespace) is proving to be tricky

Comment: @user1374796: Did you try to escape more than once ie. `\\\S`

Comment: I have had a small breakthrough you might be able to help me with, I have now found that `/\\\s/` only shows results with spaces in. So how would I now inverse this call?

Comment: @user1374796: The reverse of `\s` is `\S` or `[^\s]`. Have a try with both and add escaping as necessary, may be three or more.

Comment: this `/^(\\\S)*$/` worked perfectly in the end. Although it seems hyphens may be causing me some issues too, anyway to filter them out too?

Comment: @user1374796: add hyphen inside a character class: `[^\\\s-]`. And use a `+` instead of `*` as modifier.