# Check if string matches a word

Tags: twig

I'm trying to make use of twig's comparison `matches` and using the word regex but it's letting non words through.

Here's my code:

`{% if callback matches '/\\w+/' %}`

This lets things like `addEventListent(12929,102020210,2021021020)` through which shouldn't make it through.

Is there an issue with my implementation of the regex?

Comment: Why do you think it shouldn't go through? There are clearly word characters inside  `addEventListent(12929,102020210,2021021020)` so the [preg_match](https://ideone.com/eEstcd) won't return `false`

Comment: OK, it was my understanding that this regex checks if the whole string is a word not that if it contains words. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Add the start and ending characters to your regex as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20701035/php-regex-modify-to-only-allow-one-word)

Comment: Thank you. This fails to let words through `callback matches '/\^\w+$/u/'` is there an issue with the implementation?

Comment: You need to escape the `\w` in twig - [demo](https://twigfiddle.com/w5ensd)

Comment: Thank you! So `/^\\w+$/` works.